# Get All Images From External URL / Website

Tags: asp.net, image, url, external, html-agility-pack

This code is working nice... I dont have problem.

```
var urls = from lnks in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
  where (lnks.Name == "a" && lnks.Attributes["href"] != null &&
        (lnks.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString().Contains("jpg")
         || lnks.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString().Contains("png")
         || lnks.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString().Contains("bmp")
         || lnks.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString().Contains("jpeg")
         || lnks.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString().Contains("gif"))
        )
        select new
        {
         Url = lnks.Attributes["href"].Value
        };
```

But This one always return null:

```
var urls = from lnks in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
           where (lnks.Name == "a" || lnks.Name == "img") && 
                 (lnks.Attributes["href"] != null || lnks.Attributes["src"] != null) &&
                 (
                 lnks.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString().Contains("jpg")
                 || lnks.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString().Contains("png")
                 || lnks.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString().Contains("bmp")
                 || lnks.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString().Contains("jpeg")
                 || lnks.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString().Contains("gif")
                 || lnks.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString().Contains("jpg")
                 || lnks.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString().Contains("png")
                 || lnks.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString().Contains("bmp")
                 || lnks.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString().Contains("jpeg")
                 || lnks.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString().Contains("gif")
                 )
           select new
           {
            Url = lnks.Attributes["src"] != null ? lnks.Attributes["src"].Value : lnks.Attributes["href"].Value
           };
```

What's my mistake ? and is this a correct way to take images ?

Comment: You are doing to much in one query. Split your code into pieces and you will find your error by yourself.

Comment: Thaks for english lesson. I'm new in site and my english is terrible. And last 24 hours I did not sleep therefore I couldnt find edit button and I could not spend so much time for finding it. I feel nervous. I will try to write correct. Otherside the code is still doesnt work !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code for image nodes. Make a function out of it and you can use it for any node:

> GetLinksFromDocument(document, nodeName, linkAttributeName)

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

var urls = new List<string>();
var prefixList = new[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp", "gif" };
var document = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://jwillmer.de");

var imageNodes = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img");  
var imageLinks = imageNodes.Where(node => node.Attributes.Contains("src"))
                           .Select(node => node.Attributes["src"].Value);

urls.AddRange(imageLinks.Where(link => prefixList.Any(link.EndsWith)));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. That one is working but my first code is working too. Actually I was using a code stracture very similir that one. But I couldnt find document.DocumnetNode.Descendants("img" || "a) like something like that.  I need to take "a" -> "href" and "img" --> "src"  and prefix will be like yours... Thanks again.

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry I tried to vote up but did not work. I marked.